# Vanishing of cohomology of (subgroups of) $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-cohomology

Let $p$ be a prime and $G=\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Let $V$ be the $G$-module $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ with the standard action given by matrix multiplication. It seems that quite often the groups $H^i(H,V)$ vanish for $i=1,2$, but not always. For example, when $p=3$, the subgroup $H=C_3$ gives cohomology groups with $\mathbb{F}_3$ dimension 1 for $i=1,2$.

Having done a few Magma calculations, it seems like this only happens for subgroups $H$ whose order is 0 $\mod{p}$, but this doesn't fully characterise which subgroups have non-vanishing cohomology (the largest subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ satisfying $H^1(H,V) = H^2(H,V) = 0$ is $H=S_3$, but there are lots more subgroups with order divisible by 3).

I would like to know when these two cohomology groups vanish.

For practical purposes I can always just compute the cohomology and *see* if it vanishes, but I would still like to know if there is a criterion known that characterises these subgroups exactly.

Comment: By a general result, for all $i>0$, the cohomology group $H^i(H,M)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $H^i(P,M)$ for $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(H)$, so clearly the cohomology is zero when $|H|$ is coprime to $p$. Also if $H$ contains nontrivial scalar elements then again $H^i(H,M)=0$ for all $i>0$.

Comment: Okay, this seems to get lots of them. The subgroup of GL(2,7) generated by [4, 0, 6, 1]. [1, 0, 4, 6] and [1, 0, 6, 1] has order 42 and contains no scalars, but $H^i$ (seems to) vanish for $i$ not equal to 5,8 mod 12. In particular it vanishes for $i=1,2$.